# Why is the garbage collector invoked twice?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have problem with understanding how the garbage collector works.

I wrote this code:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    while (true)
    {
        const int size = 2000000;
        var arr = new int[size];
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

When I debug it in Visual Studio I get following process memory diagram. The yellow triangles are GC invokes. It's obvious why the GC is invoked the first time, but I don't understand why the GC is invoked a second time.

[image: proccess memory diagram]

Comment: TBH, why do you need this knowledge? GC is one of C# (and Java and so on) best features! Meaning that it does the job for you, so you don't have to bother with reference/pointer management. The best thing is, you don't need to know how and why and when it works, just that it works.

Comment: Why is it only obvious that the GC is invoked first time? Whats your thought process to expect that (not obvious)  behavior? What do you think this method does to justify only one collection?

Comment: You understand that `arr` is a new variable in each iteration of your loop? (because that's its scope)  Meaning that you're repeatedly allocating the memory and then allowing the contents to be subject to garbage collection.

Comment: But I think maybe you mean the two invocations in each 6 second cycle?

Comment: Put `const int size` outside your loop to check, but I think it's garbage collecting both `size` and `arr` on each loop.

Comment: @Tim, no, it is not garbage collecting `size`. Why would you think that?

Comment: @Tim `size` is a value type (int) allocated on the stack: Garbage collector will not handle it at all

Comment: It's only experiment for my BSc thesis. I think that first invoke in turning point is obvious, because generation probably exceed memory limit. Second invoke is doing while first allocating memory after collecting and i don't know why.

Comment: @elgonzo, just looked like an obvious solution to the two ticks in the graph. I've never needed to study garbage collection.

Comment: The array object is quite large, it gets allocated on the Large Object Heap.  You never generate any small objects that go into the normal generational heaps.  That requires the GC to switch to a different strategy to prevent OOM, details of which have never been obvious to me, but you are looking at it.  You don't have a problem.

Comment: @KrzysztofSkowronek GC could be expensive in certain situations, especially if it is running more than necessary, so knowing when it is likely to run could help work around this. Plus, what's the harm in knowing this?